# Use comboBox in Wt::Auth::RegistrationWidget

Tags: c++, wt

OS : windows8.1 64bits
compiler : vc2012 64bits
Wt version : 3.3.5

Hi, playing with the example of wt(example/features/auth2), I want to show combobox on the registration form, but there some problems need to solve

I create comboBox in the file--RegistrationView.cpp as following

```
if(field  UserDetailsModel::FavouritePetField){
    auto *box = new Wt::WComboBox;
    box->addItem("one");
    box->addItem("two");
    return box;
}else{
    return Wt::Auth::RegistrationWidget::createFormWidget(field);
}
```

The results looks like this

[image]

I expect the combobox will appear at the blue region, but it appear at red region as the picture show

If I change WComboBox to WLineEdit, everything are fine, but the layout of WComboBox always not right.

I specify the favourite pet in the templates.xml as following

```
   <label for="${id:favourite-pet}">性別:       
        ${favourite-pet class="Wt-info"}
   </label>       
   ${favourite-pet}
```

How could I let the comboBox display at the correct place?Thanks